# In R, can you separate text to columns so that values align?

Tags: r, dplyr, csv

I have a vector of text values, something like:

```
Col1
camel; cow; giraffe; panda; zebra
camel; giraffe; zebra
panda; zebra
```

And I would like to separate these values into an equal number of columns so that the values align vertically in the same columns, with NA where there are gaps so that I get:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
camel, cow, giraffe, panda, zebra
camel, NA, giraffe, NA, zebra
NA, NA, NA, panda, zebra
```

How can I accomplish this? I've tried using the 'separate' function in dplyr but this returns error messages, whilst using the 'split' function in splitshapestack allows me to separate the columns but they don't return values that are aligned vertically. I have also tried using the 'lapply' and 'match' in a similar way to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333114/sort-align-dataframe-columns-so-that-row-string-values-match-master-list-column?rq=1) but again, I keep getting error messages.

Comment: Check `splitstackshape::cSplit_e`: `cSplit_e(d, "Col1", "; ", type = "character", mode = "value", fill = NA, drop = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pivot your data a few times to align these values:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  tibble::rowid_to_column("id") %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(Col1, sep = "; ") %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = id,
                     names_from = Col1,
                     values_from = Col1) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-id) %>% 
  magrittr::set_colnames(paste0("Col", 1:ncol(.)))
```

---

**Output**

```
 Col1  Col2  Col3    Col4  Col5 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>
1 camel cow   giraffe panda zebra
2 camel NA    giraffe NA    zebra
3 NA    NA    NA      panda zebra
```

---

**How it works**

1. `rowid_to_column` keeps track of the row numbers so when the data are pivoted to a longer format, we don't lose track of which values belong in which rows.
2. `separate_rows` will separate `Col1` and pivot the data to a longer format. **Suggested by @Adam** as an improvement.
3. `pivot_wider` aligns everything into the columns you specified.

---

**Data**

```
structure(list(Col1 = c("camel; cow; giraffe; panda; zebra", 
"camel; giraffe; zebra", "panda; zebra")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: You can save the `pivot_longer()` step by using `separate_rows()` as well.

Comment: You will lose track of which values belong to which rows.

Comment: Not if you put it after your `rowid_to_column()` step!

Comment: Good point! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @LMc Thanks! The 'How it works' is really useful but I've tried running your code but I get an error message: "Error: Column 2312 must be named. Use .name_repair to specify repair." Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Try the updated code with improvements suggested by @Adam. This works on the example posted in your original question. Is this an error you're getting running it on your actual code? If so, then your example might not be capturing the nuances of your problem.

Comment: Thanks both - @LMc, it turns out I had 2 blank cells, so I replaced them with NA and re-ran the code and it worked perfectly. Problem solved!